# list of variables in R and save them

Tags: r, variables, save

Lets say there are variables named `x_1`, `x_2`, ..., `x_n` among other variables, e.g. `y`, `z`, `w` in R.

I want to save the ones with pattern `x_`, I can list them by `var_list = ls(pattern="x_")`.

But now, How can I save them, using their own name, using a for loop or something like that?
I want to have a file called `x_i.rds` on the disk containing `x_i`.

using for loop and saying `saveRDS(filename=as.character(x_1), data=x_1)` does not work.
so, perhaps something like `saveRDS(file_name=var_list[1], what_here_?)`

Comment: Perhaps `saveRDS(file_name=var_list[1], get(var_list[1]))`.

Comment: awesome, I was about to change my question to a real one where variables are really plots, and for variables perhaps `eval(parse())` may work!

Comment: Ok, I convert my comment to an answer then, since this works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `get` function allows to get a R object from its name.

So, once you have your objects names in `var_list`, you can save the first one by doing:

```
saveRDS(get(var_list[1]), file=var_list[1])
```

To save all the objects you can loop over `var_list`:

```
for(objectName in var_list){
  saveRDS(get(objectName), file = objectName)
}
```